# Cannot use second display with 12.04 and Intel 2000/3000

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I am unable to get anything to display on my second monitor, or even get the system to recognize that there is a second screen.

I am running 12.04 on a Gigabyte GA-H61M-S2PV, revision 2.0 box.  The integrated chipset is an Intel 2000/3000, and there are both a D-Dub and a DVI-D display ports on the MB.  This is the first operating system I have installed on this system.  I have a second monitor plugged into the DVI-D port via a DVI-D to D-Sub adapter.  I cannot verify that the motherboard or adapter were/are working, short of installing windows to test the theory.

When I go into the "System Settings -> Displays" control window, it shows one display.

I have rebooted with the second monitor attached, and I have perused the BIOS settings in case it might have been disabled.  So far, I have had no indication that the second monitor is recognized, not even a flicker at power on.  If I swap monitors and cables between the DVI-D and D-Dub ports, the other monitor lights up, so I know the monitor and video cable are not the issue.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use the vga to dvi converter it won't work. This motherboard dvi output port is not supporterd by the converter. You can check the technical spec [here](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4294#sp).